# android:background is not working with WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

For some reason im unable to change the background color of an empty webView in xml using `android:background`. Although I could change it in java code using something like this:

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D4CAB4"));
```

But I prefer to do it in xml and I cant find the reason why `android:background` is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one can set WebView background color in xml layout the answer is **"NO"** and the reason behind is:

1. Set Background Color of WebView. (XML LAYOUT)
2. You load data on webView in activity class.
3. The background you set in the step 1 will be ignored and default color will be set.
4. The only method left is to set the background of WebView after the data is loaded.

I hope this can help you to understand the case here.

Comment: is it possible to change the default color?

Comment: @wutzebaer Exactly. You'd expect the 'default color' to be the `backgroundColor`.